# Telegram login widget not showing up

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

Sorry I am a total newb.
I deployed this site
https://visionary-cupcake-b69c3d.netlify.app/

1. used this part of the code for the test

```
    </script>
    <!-- Start of the added Telegram script -->
  <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="Guardian200_bot" data-size="large" data-auth-url="ya.ru"></script>
    </script>
    <!-- End of the added Telegram script -->
```

2. my bot is regstered and I specifiyed [visionary-cupcake-b69c3d.netlify.app] as a domain
3. site is using https as required

Yet login widget is not showing up. Why it could be?

I redeployed it few times, checked various settings from there https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have put the `<script>` tag inside the `<head>`. Put it somewhere inside the `<body>`, so it can be displayed when the button component is created.

```html
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- your app -->
        <!-- the script tag provided by Telegram wherever you want the button to be --->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped.  perhaps you can guide me a bit further?

My end goal is to have a private web page that is only accessible to my private telegram group members. 

What to read?